# I wan't to have curved Container that stacks over SliverAppBar - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

[image]

[image]

The picture is in SliverAppBar which is pinned. How do I create a curved container that stacks over SliverAppBar?

I know I could use stack and remove SliverAppBar entirely. But want the SliverAppBar pinned effect  along with the curved Container that slightly holders on the edges of SliverAppBar. How can the picture be achived?

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    SliverAppBar(
      leading: Icon(
        Icons.arrow_back,
        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
      ),
      title: Text(
        'Course Details',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 25,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
      centerTitle: true,
      expandedHeight: size.height * .4,
      pinned: true,
      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
        background: Image.asset(
          "${Configs.rootImgUrl}/course_details.png",
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: Container(
        height: 600,
        padding: margin.cave,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
            topRight: Radius.circular(30),
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            ...
          ]
        ),
  ]),
```